# UIPicker selectRow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I am trying to select the first row as default..
Here i tried

```
-(void)pickerViewLoaded{

   [pickerView setShowSelectionIndicator:YES];
   pickerView.delegate = self;
   [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
   [pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES]
}
```

It works fine when i call this method on viewDidLoad() which call didSelectRow method but it is selecting the second row of that component not first one.
when i call with [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES] then it never call didSelectRow method.

another problem is when i call pickerViewLoaded method on selection of segmented control it does not call the didSelectRow method. i still could not figure when it may call with viewDidLoad then why not with segmentedControl.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 2):

seems to be a old thread, anyway I thought of sharing my experience.

I had the same issue and moved the

```
[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

to

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

I call the *selectRow:inComponent:animated* only after returning the titleForRow called for last-row using a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the question has been raised from the dead...

I think selectRow uses an index that starts at 0 - not 1. So 0 is the first row, and 1 is the second row.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem and figured it out: The delegate doesn't get called, if the selected row doesn't change. Also, row 0 is selected by default, so re-selecting row 0 in `viewDidLoad` doesn't trigger the delegate. In my case I was able to call the delegate method directly, maybe that's the solution in your case, too.